# Reinstalling iPhone code signing certificates after new Leopard install

Tags: iphone, xcode, cryptography, certificate

Back story:

- Small-time iPhone developer, even have a (tiny) app on the App Store, so I've navigated the code-signing process before.
- Performed the appropriate backups of my crypto certs (as outlined in the "Saving your Private Key and Transferring to other Systems" section of [iPhone Developer Program 
  Standard Program Portal User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_developer_program_user_guide/iphone_developer_program_user_guide__standard_program_v2.4.pdf)).  I even have the previous full-disk image, if necessary.
- Performed a full Leopard reinstall.
- Installed my private key from the .p12 files created during backup process *and* my development certificate (re-downloaded from "Current Development Certificates" section of my  iPhone Developer Program Portal)

iPhone developers who've gone through the same process: Can I use my old certificates, or must I go through all or part of the private key generation, CSR, and cert install process?  If so, what are the steps to properly reinstall my certs so that Xcode recognizes them (and I can get back to the true goal - testing on my iPhone hardware again)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your provisioning profiles and that *should* be it. But I emphasize "should" because I had trouble getting it back to work, too. I'm suspecting Keychain Access to be buggy (but don't quote me, I cannot prove it).

Some copying-keys-and-certificates-restarting-xcode-rebooting-device craziness later it simply worked for no obvious reason. It's definitely possible to use old keys, certificates, and profiles after a clean install.

Comment: Installed provisioning profile and it worked perfectly on the first try.  I can't believe I neglected that step.  *facepalm*

Thanks!